# 返り値がNullになるようなクラスの型を持つ変数を定義したい

Tags: ruby, d

Ruby初心者です．
返り値がNullになるようなクラスの型を持つ変数を定義したいです．
ただ，クラスの継承は避けたいです．
D言語で例をいいますと，Nullableがあります．
そのような書き方はできなければできないで結構です．
以下のようなやり方で強引に書く予定です．
ご教授お願い致します．

例えば以下のような感じのコードが書きたいです．

```
class AAA
  def initialize
    @_t1 = Complex(0.0, 0.0)  # ここでNullを返す引数を明示しないでCCC型の変数_t1を宣言したい
  end
  attr_accessor :_t1
end

class BBB
  aaa = AAA.new
  aaa._t1 = CCC.new(a, b, c)  # 別の .rb ファイルに定義されているとする
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ruby に型はないので、特定の変数に代入されるクラスの種類を指定することはできません。(ゲッタとセッタを分離して、セッタでオブジェクトのクラスを調べて手動で例外を投げる、とかしない限り)

Comment: わかりました．上記のようにダミーの変数を用意してそこに代入する形で強引にやりたいと思います．ご回答ありがとうございます．